# BATV; What is it and how is it configured?

Tags: php, html, linux, security, email

I have tested my email server on allaboutspam.com to see why the emails are beeing considered spam by hotmail and gmail servers.

The results was amongst other faults, the BATV.

This is the complete result from allaboutspam.com on my BATV:

*BATV is a mechanism wherein an outgoing Email server adds a tag to the Envelope From address of all outgoing Emails. For example, if an Email address goes out with From address as `<info@allaboutspam.com>`, the Envelope From is changed to `<prvs=SBDGAUJ=info@allaboutspam.com>`, where 'SBDGAUJ' is the added tag. This tag is generated using an internal mechanism and is different for each email sent.
If any bounce is received by the Incoming email servers, they are checked to see if the Bounce address has the proper tag (in above case 'SBDGAUJ'). If not, the email is rejected.*

Could somebody explain this in simpler words... How is it configured?

currently I have this setup when sending email with php:

```
$mail_message="text_text_text_text";

$headers="MIME-Version: 1.0"."\n";
$headers.="Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"."\n";
$headers.="From: Skuffen <no-reply@domain.se>"."\n";
$subject="SUBJECT HERE";

mail($email, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $mail_message, $headers, '-fno-reply@domain.se');
```

This is a swedish language so you know (utf-8)...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to set this up in your Mail Transfer Agent. The PHP mail() command sends mail through the local sendmail (or compatible, like Exim, Postfix or Qmail) installation. That's where BATV needs to be configured.

If you are on a simple shared hosting, contact your hosting provider.